# Trying to upload jar file to hortonworks, from windows to hortonworks sandbox in oracle vm virtual box

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to upload a jar file (WordCount.jar that runs MapReduce code). I am using pscp to try to upload the file.

I am using the command line in windows command

```
pscp.exe WordCount.jar root@192.168.56.101:/usr/root
```

And after a bit of a wait, it responds with:

> Fatal: Network error: Connection time out

Then in my Oracle VM VirtualBox, with Hortonworks SandBox 2.0, the console says,

```
...
  next_to_watch.status <0>
e1000 0000:00:08.0: eth1: Detected Tx Unit Hang
  Tx Queue             <0>
  TDH                  <0>
  TDT                  <1>
  next_to_use          <1>
  next_to_clean        <0>
buffer_info[next_to_clean]
  time_stamp           <1001eef44>
  next_to_watch        <0>
  jiffies              <1001f3b23>
  next_to_watch.status <0>
...
e1000 0000:00:08.0: eth1: reset apater
```

My network settings, have adapter 1: attached to NAT

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try out the **Shared Folders** guest additions in VirtualBox to ship/share your jar file with the sandbox.

[Here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868) is a tutorial about shared folders.